Error of truncated Taylor Series for matrix inverse approximation
I want to use Theorem 9.2.3 from this book to compute an error bound for matrix inverse using Taylor Series
Golub, Gene H.; Van Loan, Charles F., Matrix computations, Oxford: North Oxford Academic; Baltimore, Maryland: The Johns Hopkins University Press. XVI, 476 p. (1983). ZBL0559.65011.
Given that $f(A)=A^{-1}$ and $f^{(n)}(A)=(-1)^{n}n!A^{-1-n}$, RHS simplfies to:
\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\frac{n}{(q+1)!}\max_{0 \leq s \leq 1}\norm{ X^{q+1}(-1)^{q+1}\frac{(q+1)!}{s^{q+1}}X^{-q-1}}
\end{equation*}
which is infinity for $s=0$, so I got confused, where am I wrong?
Also, it says that Taylor Series is only effective near origin:

I don't see why, I mean we can write taylor series around any point, not only zero, why it consider only Taylor Series around zero? One can write taylor series around $s$ such that $s$ is the average of largest and smallest eigenvalue of $A$.
